# Error childview method "Error: <spyOn> : could not find an object to spy upon for"

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I need to test that one method calls to child method. I tried with spyOn but return one error "Error:  : could not find an object to spy upon for nuevaTarea()". can someone give me a hand with this?

Testing class:

```
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ListaTareasComponent],
      providers: [
        ListaTareasContenidoComponent,
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ListaTareasComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();  });


  it('should call to anadirTarea', () => {
    spyOn(
      component.ListaTareasContenidoComponent,
      'nuevaTarea'
    ).and.callThrough();
    component.anadirTarea(tarea);
    expect(
      component.ListaTareasContenidoComponent?.nuevaTarea
    ).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
```

Parent class:

```
  @ViewChild(ListaTareasContenidoComponent)
  ListaTareasContenidoComponent!: ListaTareasContenidoComponent;

  crear: boolean = false;
  borrar: boolean = false;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }


  anadirTarea(tareas: ITareas) {
    this.ListaTareasContenidoComponent?.nuevaTarea(tareas);
  }

}
```

Child class:

```
  
  listaTareas: any | undefined;

  constructor(private tareasService: TareasService, private router: Router) {
  
    this.tareasService
      .getTareas()
      .subscribe((respuesta: any) => (this.listaTareas = respuesta['data']));

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  nuevaTarea(tarea: ITareas) {
      this.listaTareas.push(tarea);
    
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: put `ListaTareasContenidoComponent` also to `declarations` array

Comment: Hi @Andrei, Thanks for answer. I tried to put child on declarations but then all test return Error.

Comment: is the error message still the same?

Comment: OMG! No! Now the error comes from not having HttpClientModule. Thanks a lot! 3 days for that shit...